# What is non injective singular n-simplex used for?

Tags: homology-cohomology

The Singular_homology article of Wikipedia mentions singular n-simplex doesn't have to be injective. But when used for integration on chains, it is always injective or it doesn't make sense. Then what is the non-injective use case when the non-injectiveness is important for the application?

Comment: Why does it have to be injective for integration (either meaning applying a singular cochain to a chain, or integrating the pullback of the differential form (smooth singular homology) if you want to prove de Rham's theorem) to make sense?

Comment: @user10354138 The Differential_form article of Wikipedia says "A k-chain is a formal sum of smooth embeddings D → M. " which make me think it is also injective when integrating. Also I thought integration on chain is cut the manifold into pieces each of which is diffeomorphism to standard k-simplex then integrate them on $R^n$. Although you can make this map non injective too but it doesn't bring any essential effect.

Comment: That is a different type of chain.  Any homology theory will have its own chains.

Comment: While wikipedia can be great at giving you a quick and dirty introduction to a mathematical subject, it can be dangerous to overintepret the content of a wikipedia page. Integration over a non-injective singular simplex makes perfect sense as long as the defining map is smooth: pull back the form and integrate on the domain. The theory of de Rham cohomology uses such integrals all the time, to prove the major theorems, for example.